# Executing Terminal commands in MobileSafari

Tags: ios, terminal, mobile-safari, jailbreak

I'd like to execute a terminal command in MobileSafari on a jailbroken iPhone, is it possible? If so, what language/tools/steps/crap/etc is required to do this? Thanks

Comment: Do you still want an answer here?